# Event over KineticJS Shape which renders SVG

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, kineticjs

I am newbee to kinetic js. i try to load an svg using canvg library to kinetic js. and when i tried to attach an event to the svg i am not able to do that. please see the code below.

```
var repo = new Kinetic.Path ({
  x: 0, y: 0,
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  drawFunc: function (canvas) {
    canvas.getContext().drawSvg("http://localhost:3000/repo.svg", 0, 0, 250, 250);
  }
});

repo.on('mouseover', function(event)    {
  alert('test');
});

layer.add(repo);
```

Comment: Did you check this tutorial http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-world-map-svg-path-with-kineticjs/ ? I do not see `data` variable being assigned. Does this code draws the svg or its not drawing it altogether? I suggest you make a fiddle, would be much easier to play with

Comment: yes the code draws the svg.. but i am not able to attach the event..

Comment: @Ani i tried to add it to jsfiddle.. its not working. i think canvg don't support urls.